# How to get a list of virtual machines in Azure with c#?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to get a list of my VMS on Azure using C#. I´ve found this nugget package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute` but I'm not able to create the client of it. What I´ve tried:

```
 public class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
    {
        var authenticationContext =
            new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxx", clientSecret: "{clientSecret}");

        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/",
            clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
    }
    public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (AuthenticationToken == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");
        }



        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //request.Version = new Version(apiVersion);
        await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }
}
```

But I am getting a compilation error on this class saying that `AuthenticationContext` namespace could not be found. I can't find about how to create this simple client on docs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up a service principal (SP)?  Our documentation for SDK auth using SP can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet#mgmt-auth

You will need to add the following nuget packages to your project.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
```

Comment: Hi Ken, I´m reading this doc and I found this `Service principals provide a way to create a non-interactive account associated with your identity to which you grant only the privileges your app needs to run.`. Thats great, but just dont understand how to create a "user" for my app, without portal login, and just with permission to list my VM´s. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: I mean, I will create a SP with this powershell command but it will create another user? If yes, where I can change the roles and permissions for this user?

Comment: You will see the SP under "App Registration" under your Azure AD.  You can also see it under the IAM blade for resources.  Details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Answer (score 0):

This is the nuget package you need: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

`Compute` nuget is necessary for VM specific stuff. For authentication you need the one I've posted.